# how to extend wpf combo box to bind data?

Tags: wpf, combobox, data-binding

i need to bind a collection of objects to a combo box which i can use in different forms. so i want create a custom control which binds the collection to the combo box? how t do it by extending combo box? also how can i define the ItemData template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to *extend* `ComboBox`? You can directly bind `ComboBox` to a collection using `ItemsSource` property! **[This](http://www.garvander.com/wpf)** and **[this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prathore/WPFComboBox01132009062811AM/WPFComboBox.aspx)** page explains more about data binding and using `ItemTemplate` with `ComboBox`. Or, you can explore more on **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753382%28VS.85%29.aspx)**.

Comment: +1, Shaihan, I think you should check out WPF Unleashed by Adam Nathan; it's a very good book on this topic